# How to fix the size of JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have this jframe :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHvDQ.png]

Everytime I click on "add JComboBox" , 2 JComboBoxes will be added ,but the problem is the size of JComboxBox gets smaller.

They look like this :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAuxE.png]

This is a part of my code

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    
    JComboBox comboBox_2 = new JComboBox();
    comboBox_2.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"Personnages", "Annimaux ", "Plantes", "Lieux ", "Quartier"}));
    cb = new JComboBox();
    req();
    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("add JComboBox");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JComboBox jcb = new JComboBox();
            jcb.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"Personnages", "Animaux ", "Plantes", "Lieux ", "Quartier"}));
     jcb1 = new JComboBox(); 
            req1();
         
            panel.add(jcb);
            panel.add(jcb1); 
            panel.revalidate();} });
    GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(149)
                        .addComponent(btnNewButton)
                        .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(btnRemove))
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(panel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 521, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap()));
    groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
            .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(panel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 86, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 90, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(btnNewButton)
                    .addComponent(btnRemove))
                .addGap(51)));
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 10, 10));
    panel.add(comboBox_2);
    panel.add(cb);`
```

Is there any way to avoid this problem and fix  the size of the JComboBox ?

Comment: You need to post your code

Comment: Post a proper [mre] when asking a question. A picture doesn't give us any idea of what your code is.

Answer (score 1):

Having not seen your code, this is just speculating. But to me, it seems like the way to fix it would be use a JScrollPane, like

```
public JPanel createMultiAddPanel (Container toAddTo) {
  JPanel p = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
  JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(p);
  toAddTo.add(sp);
  return p;
}
```

Now you can keep adding JComboBoxes to your JPanel and they won't shrink

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your layout manager.

It looks like you are adding your components to a panel using a `GridLayout`.

The height of the GridLayout is then also constrained by the layout mananger of the parent panel.

The solution is to use a different layout manager or combination of layout managers.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Edit:

Don't use the IDE to generate your code. It is not easy to customize the code to allow for dynamic changes.

It still appears to me that you are using a GridLayout. The GridLayout will make the cells the same size. So you have one cell for the combo boxes. As you add more combo boxes they becomes smaller to fit in the fixed space allocated to the cell. The buttons take up the same space, even though they don't need all the space.

Comment: See edit. Until you post a proper [mre] that does not use IDE generated code, I can't give specific help.

Answer (score -2):

Use:

```
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(X,Y));
```

Comment: See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)